# Nexus - No component/assets found in repository

Tags: nexus

I am new to nexus, so I don't know much, my problem or question or doubt is the following is that when I run nexus and go to Browse, a list of the maven or nuget components is shown, but at the moment of entering these components are empty, so I don't know why this case occurs.

[Nexus dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI0Wj.png)

Comment: Did you enable anonymous access ? are you logged in ? did you push any artefacts to your repository ? Your question misses a lot of details to understand your exact situation and help you out....

Comment: A common misconception with NXRM3 is that browse shows components from the remotes.  It does not, it only shows components that are in your NXRM instance.  Other than that the previous comments questions are all good.  You could try `curl -u admin:admin123 -v -4 http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-central/abbot/abbot/0.13.0/abbot-0.13.0.pom` and see if anything shows up there after doing so (this assumes your admin password is admin123, you haven't disabled admin, you kept the deault maven-central repo and you have permissions to browse or can get them).